# UnityEngine.Transform.RotateAroundLocal is obsolete. Now what?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to fix this error since unity5. If I just use rotate the object hardly moves at all.

```
transform.RotateAroundLocal(playerCamera.transform.up, -Mathf.Deg2Rad * (rotationSystem.xRotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")));
```

Comment: Your answer is [here answered by Unity community](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/581017/whats-the-function-to-replace-the-obsolete-rotatea.html). P.S. Using search engines seems to be a nice idea for questions that already might have answers :)

Answer (score 1):

They have retired RotateAroundLocal, but you with Unity 5 you can use transform.Rotate:

```
transform.Rotate(playerCamera.transform.up, -Mathf.Deg2Rad * (rotationSystem.xRotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")), Space.World);
```

There reference for this is:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Answer (score 0):

```
transform.RotateAroundLocal(axis, angle);
```

is equivalent to:

```
transform.Rotate(axis, angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg, Space.World);
```

so the Rad2Deg and Deg2Rad cancel out and you get:

```
transform.Rotate(playerCamera.transform.up, -rotationSystem.xRotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Space.World);
```